# PHPMailer class not found, path doesn't exist even though I used PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer and required /vendor/autoload.php

Tags: php, phpmailer

Exact error being given:Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer' not found in C:\wamp64\www\tutoring\web\environment.php on line 37

My code:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require __DIR__ . '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Line 37:

```
// This is inside of a function but the uses and require are not
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

My file tree:

[image: vendor folder and environment.php both in web folder]

autoload is in the right place and so is the PHPMailer class:

[image: autoload is in the right place and so is the PHPMailer class]

I've been trying to fix this for the past 2 hours. Every post I've seen with this issue has been resolved with something that doesn't fix mine.

Comment: Have you rebuilt the autoloader since adding the PHPMailer library? Did you try putting the `require` line before the `use` lines? I'm not sure if the order matters, but if it does then it's almost certain that the order you have would be the wrong one.

Comment: Try `require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';`. Note the `/` before `..`

Comment: @GregSchmidt the `use` statements should definitely come first

Comment: That's weird, because I use a framework where the autoloader is included long before any `use` statements happen.

Answer (score -1):

Have you include/require phpmailerautoload.php?,

This works for me,

```
require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
```

Comment: It just says it failed to open stream. I also tried require_once('../vendor/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'); which also failed to open stream.

Comment: check your path manually and check your included path , is there a typo or someting ? my email.php is located beside PHPMailer folder, and there is directly PHPMailerAutoload.php in PHPMailer folder

Comment: If your code says that, you're using a very old version of PHPMailer and should upgrade.